# ANOVA on ranks?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, ranks

Once in a statistics class I've seen the suggestion that one non-parametric approach for ANOVA would be to perform the ANOVA analysis on the *ranks* of the original data (basically as an alternative to Kruskal-Wallis). In an answer to a different question ([Rank transformed 2-way ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11141/rank-transformed-2-way-anova/11144#11144)), @FrankHarrel suggests that "A two-way ANOVA on ranks is not based on strong statistical principles."

So, more generally, is it advisable/sane to do ANOVA on ranks? And why?

Comment: *One* way ANOVA on ranks (as long as you correctly compute significance via the permutation distribution of the test statistic under the null) *is* the Kruskal-Wallis. However, in the case of two- (and higher-) way ANOVA, things become somewhat more complicated. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANOVA_on_ranks). The whole article and its references have both some good news and some bad news.